# Is 1 hour 50 minutes enough time to transfer at DFW international to domestic?

Tags: indian-citizens, short-connections, dfw

Flying from Chennai (MAA) to Seattle. Change over at London (BA to AA) and  at DFW ( AA to AA). Arriving DFW 6.45pm @ Terminal-D and Departing 8.35pm (Terminal not known). Is this 1h50m sufficient for TSA check and catching my connecting flight to Seattle? How is the rowd in evening on Saturday

Comment: Did you make a mistake on the arrival/departure times or the interval? 8:35 - 6:45 is 1 hr 50 min.

Comment: Yes the interval is 1hr 50 min. Is it too short for Immigration check and to rush to catch my connecting flight to Seattle?

Comment: DFW is HUGE, but has a shuttle train and lots of moving sidewalks to make it easy to get around quickly.  I haven't gone through Immigration at DFW, but I know you can get to your gate fairly quickly.

Comment: I think I only made that connection once, and it was pretty quick, though of course it may vary depending on your status/visa and possibly on variable queues, but IIRC DFW is a breeze compared to MIA for instance.

Comment: I would recommend you look at a map in advance. DFW is a large airport and it really helps to know how you plan to get between the gates. https://www.dfwairport.com/connect/index.php

Comment: Terminal D is the International terminal at DFW, but many domestic flights on larger aircraft also use this terminal.  The AirTrans ( ? ) train is inside security for transportation to other terminals so you'll just need to clear customs; trains depart every 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

If the airline sold you that as a single ticket, they have every expectation that the connection time is sufficient to clear all checks.

Comment: Visiting US  first time having  B1/B2 visa travelling in American Airlines (Economy class)